# PHP save data in sql in multiform

Tags: php, sql

I'm using a multiform PHP script given [here](http://ivanvillareal.com/development/dynamic-multi-form-on-same-page-with-jquery-and-php/). It is basically a kind of form completion in multiple steps on the same page. I'm just a beginner in PHP, so I was taking idea from this script.
What I failed to understand is: "How to store the data input by the user in SQL tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `save` function, instead of saving data into the `$_SESSION` (here: `$_SESSION[$step][$key] = $val;`), save it your SQL database.

But be careful. You will have to update the script to retrieve information from the database instead of from the `$_SESSION` when you set the value in each input tag.

**edit:**

The `save` function is where you will store each data input from user. Instead of :

```
function save($step, $data) {
    //$_SESSION[$step] = $data;
    $fields = explode('&',$data);
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $keyVal = explode('=', $field);
        $key = urldecode($keyVal[0]);
        $val = urldecode($keyVal[1]);
        $_SESSION[$step][$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

You should have something like that (**the sql queries aren't good, it's just an example**):

```
function save($step, $data)
{
  //$_SESSION[$step] = $data;
  $fields = explode('&',$data);
  $sql    = "INSERT INTO `ma_table` (`step`, `key`, `val`) VALUES ";

  foreach ($fields as $field)
  {
    $keyVal = explode('=', $field);
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($keyVal[0]);
    $val = mysql_real_escape_string($keyVal[1]);

    $sql .= "('" . $step . "', '" . $key . "', '" . $val . "')";
  }

  mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: LOL just writing: In the example, you can go back to previous pages, so you'll have to retrieve it too!

Comment: @j0k: Can you explain in a more elaborate manner? I'm quite new to PHP.

Comment: @Waygood: Is there any way where if I go back, the fields become empty again after getting saved in the SQL?